# C Pointer and Memory Allocation: Realloc Arrays and Pointer Passing

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, reference

For those experienced with C, this will be a simple memory allocation/referencing problem:

Here are my data structures:

```
struct configsection {
    char *name;
    unsigned int numopts;
    configoption *options;
};
typedef struct configsection configsection;

struct configfile {
    unsigned int numsections;
    configsection *sections;
};
typedef struct configfile configfile;
```

Here are my routines for initializing a configsection or configfile, and for adding a configsection to a configfile:

```
// Initialize a configfile structure (0 sections)
void init_file(configfile *cf) {
    cf = malloc(sizeof(configfile));
    cf->numsections = 0;
}
// Initialize a configsection structure with a name (and 0 options)
void init_sec(configsection *sec, char *name) {
    sec = malloc(sizeof(configsection));
    sec->numopts = 0;
    sec->name = name;
    printf("%s\n", sec->name);
}
// Add a section to a configfile
void add_sec(configfile *cf, configsection *sec) {
    // Increase the size indicator by 1
    cf->numsections = cf->numsections + 1;
    // Reallocate the array to accommodate one more item
    cf->sections = realloc(cf->sections, sizeof(configsection)*cf->numsections);
    // Insert the new item
    cf->sections[cf->numsections] = *sec;
}
```

I believe my problem originates in my init_sec() function.  Here is an example:

```
int main(void) {

// Initialize test configfile
configfile *cf;
init_file(cf);

// Initialize test configsections
configsection *testcs1;
init_sec(testcs1, "Test Section 1");
// Try printing the value that should have just been stored
printf("test name = %s\n", testcs1->name);
```

Although the `printf()` in `init_sec()` successfully prints the name I just stored in the configsection, attempting the same thing in the `printf()` of `main()` produces a segmentation fault.  Further, `addsec()` produces a segmentation fault.

Comment: @IntermediateHacker: Thanks.  Is there a reason for this?

Comment: well, not if you're just using standard C. but sometimes, with GObject etc. it may cause problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This routine should be

```
void init_file(configfile **cf) { 
    *cf = malloc(sizeof(configfile)); 
    (*cf)->numsections = 0;
    (*cf)->sections = NULL; // You forgot to initialise this.
}
```

i.e. called by `init_file(&myconfigfilepointer);` so the `malloc` return value gets passed back.

Need to do the same trick for `init_sec`

This function is incorrect - here is a corrected version

```
void add_sec(configfile *cf, configsection *sec) {     
    // Increase the size indicator by 1     
    // Reallocate the array to accommodate one more item     
    cf->sections = realloc(cf->sections, sizeof(configsection)*(1 + cf->numsections));     
    // Insert the new item     
    cf->sections[cf->numsections] = *sec; // Since arrays start at 0     
    cf->numsections = cf->numsections + 1;     
}
```

You then need to adjust the calls in `main`

Comment: With () added like this: `(*cf)->sections`, I think this might be the solution.

Comment: Ah, yes.  You noticed that I was assigning my array values incorrectly.  Excellent!

Answer (score 2):

At no point do you initialise `cf->sections`, which means when you try to `realloc` it the first time, you're passing rubbish. Adding:

```
 cf->sections = NULL;
```

to `init_file` should help.

You're also not checking any return codes, but you knew that yes?

Comment: hehe, I missed that one also +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a pointer of the value to be updated... eg:

```
// Initialize a configfile structure (0 sections)
void init_file(configfile **cf) {
    *cf = malloc(sizeof(configfile));
    (*cf)->numsections = 0;
}

configfile *var;
init_file(&var);
printf("%d\n", var->numsections);
```

Otherwise you are just updating the local pointer *cf and not the original passed in value

Comment: Hmmm...  Getting there.  `*cf->numsections = 0;` produces a "not a structure or union" error.

Comment: added order of operation bracing to the answer, give that a go.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. You need `(*cf)->numsections = 0` or `(*cf).numsections = 0` - they are equivalent - not a combination of both. Update: my mistake - see below.

Comment: @Geoffrey: Oh, yes!  I've seen that before!  Thank you.

Comment: @Tim - I thought I fixed that??? its not completely wrong, its a syntax error, and `(*cf).numsections` is invalid, its a pointer to a pointer in the definition.

Comment: Apologies - I missed that you had added another layer of indirection - my fault.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a problem in `init_sec`

```
// Initialize a configsection structure with a name (and 0 options)
void init_sec(configsection *sec, char *name) {
    sec = malloc(sizeof(configsection));
    sec->numopts = 0;
    sec->name = name;
    printf("%s\n", sec->name);
}
```

You're just copying the name pointer here, which means, that it points to the original storage of name. If you'd call `init_sec` like this

```
configsection foobar()
{
    configsection sec;
    char name[80];

    get_name(name);
    init_sec(sec, name);
    return sec;    
}
```

The `name` pointer became invalid the moment `foobar` returned. You need to duplicate the string and keep your private copy around. In `init_sec`:

```
    sec->name = strdup(name);
```

But there's more. In the very first line of `init_sec` you're overwriting the pointer that was passed to `init_sec` with the one of malloc. So the new pointer never gets passed back to the calle. Either use a pointer to a pointer, don't take a configsection pointer at all (after all, you're allocating), but just return the allocated pointer: Complete corrected  function:

```
// Initialize a configsection structure with a name (and 0 options)
configsection* init_sec(char *name) {
    configsection *sec = malloc(sizeof(configsection));
    sec->numopts = 0;
    sec->name = name;
    printf("%s\n", sec->name);
    return sec;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this appears to be correct.  If I attempt to access the name value outside of the initialization function, then I simply get `(null)`.

Comment: @thoughtadvances: Sorry, I prematurely clicked "answer". You've got two problems there. One is the not duplicated name string, the other, that you're allocating memory, but never pass back the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to really rethink how function arguments are passed in C and what pointers are. Your problem has nothing to do with memory allocation. Rather, your code is assigning a pointer to dynamically allocated memory only to a *local variable*, of which the calling code knows nothing.

While you could solve the problem by passing a pointer to the caller's pointer (i.e. a double pointer), this is not necessarily the most elegant or most usual way of handling things. Rather, you should *return* the result of the allocation from the function. While you're at it, you should also use `calloc` to zero out the memory right away. Wrapping it all up:

```
typedef struct substuff_
{
    int a;
    double b;
} substuff;

typedef struct stuff_
{
    unsigned int n;
    substuff * data;
} stuff;

substuff * init_substuff()
{
    substuff * const p = malloc(sizeof *p);
    if (p) { p->a = 5; p->b = -0.5; }
    return p;
}

stuff * init_stuff()
{
    substuff * const p = init_substuff();
    if (!p) return NULL;

    stuff * const q = malloc(sizeof *q);
    if (q) { q->n = 10; q->data = p; }
    return q;
}
```

As an exercise, you should write the corresponding functions `void free_substuff(substuff *)` and `void free_stuff(stuff *)`.

Comment: This solution looks much more elegant.  I find it difficult to keep track of what is pointing to what in a double pointer situation.  I will attempt to implement this.